# How to access response body in spring WebClient Retry?

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, project-reactor, spring-webclient

I have a `WebClient` that makes use of retries:

```
webClient.retryWhen(
   Retry.backoff(3, Duration.ofSeconds(3)).filter(this::isRetryable)
)

private boolean isRetryable(Throwable throwable) {
    //TODO how access the json body?
}
```

Question: how can I evaluate the json response body during retry? Because I want to base the decision not only on status code, but on error content returned.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're using the `retrieve()` method of webclient, which will always throw an exception if the status code signals an error. You probably want to use `exchangeToMono()` instead, which won't throw an exception on a non-2xx status code, instead providing you the response to do as you please:

```
WebClient.create("http://my-endpoint.abc/endpoint")
        .get()
        .exchangeToMono(cr -> cr.bodyToMono(String.class).map(body -> {
            //return `Mono.error()` here if invalid - you have access to both body + statuscode (via cr.statusCode())
        })).retryWhen(
            Retry.backoff(3, Duration.ofSeconds(3)).filter(e -> e instanceof ExceptionThrownAbove)
        );
```